# How could it be that 80% of townspeople were farmers during the Edo period in Japan?

Tags: japan, agriculture, tokugawa-era

I've read in the book "[A modern history of Japan](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Modern-History-Japan-Tokugawa-Present/dp/0195339223)" by Andrew Gordon and other articles, that most of the Japanese townspeople were farmers(about 80% I suppose) during the Edo period. But according to the Wikipedia article [Agriculture, forestry, and fishing in Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agriculture,_forestry,_and_fishing_in_Japan) and some satellite maps, only about one-fifth of Japan's land is suitable for cultivation.

I'm a bit confused, how is this possible? 80% of townspeople worked on only 20% of the whole land?

Comment: Welcome to HistorySE, P.Alipoor! It looks as if you'd assume for 80% of farmers to work on 80% of the whole available landmass? When the first farmers appeared in Japan, 100% of people worked on 0.00001% of the land? Is this a simple misunderstanding and less a history problem but math, geography and logic? As farmers aren't evenly distributed across the land anywhere, why should they in Edo Japan?

Comment: Japanese farmers produced ... [rice on terraced fields](https://www.tsunagujapan.com/japans-terraced-rice-fields-will-take-your-breath-away/), among other crops.

Comment: First, explain why townspeople were farmers.

Comment: @T.E.D.: no, they only occupy (and work) a fraction of that.

Comment: @jamesqf Presumably ["villagers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edo-period_village) is closer to the mark.

Comment: You have misquoted Gordon.  He actually says: "_Roughly 80 percent of the population was farmers.  The remainder were townspeople of various sorts_" (p16 of the paperback edition)

Comment: What % has your research led you to expect? 80% sounds rather low to me.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace The original quote most probably comes from the population of small villages / hamlets vs bigger towns, which was about 80 vs 20%. These are obviously rough numbers, and not counting that many town people also involved with agriculture (even now). Considering the size of cites like Tokyo (Edo), it makes sense.

Comment: Japan may look tiny on a world map, but it's actually as big as Germany by area.

Comment: Funny question. I was expecting small gardens within cities :)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The total land area of Japan is around [146,000 square miles](https://www.google.com/search?q=japan+land+area&oq=japan+land+area&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.3086j1j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  20% of that works out around 29,000 square miles or 18.6 million acres.

The population of Tokugawa japan was around [30 million people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographic_history_of_Japan_before_the_Meiji_Restoration#Total_population_2).  80% of that is 24 million people.  This gives each farmer roughly 3/4s of an acre.

The basic unit of land in Japan was [the cho](https://bergental.eastkingdom.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Agriculture-in-Japan-during-the-late-Medieval-period.pdf), which was roughly 2.5 acres.  This produced [roughly 10 koku](https://bergental.eastkingdom.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Agriculture-in-Japan-during-the-late-Medieval-period.pdf).  A "koku" was the amount of rice needed to feed one person for one year.  Simple math gives 4 koku an acre, and therefore 3 koku for 3/4s of an acre.  In other words, in theory at least, each person has enough land to grow rice for three.

Thus, if 80% of the population is working 20% of the land in Tokugawa Japan, then they are easily growing enough to feed themselves plus the remaining 20% who are not farmers.

Now of course that's the ideal case, and bad weather, war and other mishaps are going to negatively affect that to the point where in actual fact there were periods of starvation and food related unrest.  But it means that "80% of townspeople worked on only 20% of the whole land" is perfectly believable.

Comment: Just to add to this otherwise great answer, for those who never had the curiosity to research what an acre is and why it is what it is, an acre roughly corresponds to what a peasant was able to plow in a day.

Comment: Don't forget that people are grouped into families. 24 million people was probably something like 4-5 million families, running a farm together.

Comment: Right, people weren't working individual plots, but families were working in common.  Presumably the "cho" indicated a common basic farm unit.

Comment: Wikipedia contradicts the linked article saying that the "koku" was ~278 liters during the Tokugawa shogunate. Then redefined to be ~180 in 1891, shortly after the end of Tokugawa. ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koku

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: ...which is typical for many imperial measurements: *Sounds* intuitive, but is terribly imprecise. Plow with what? A horse, or an oxen? By hand? If the ground is difficult to plow, does an acre become smaller? (OK, I will relent, it's what could be plowed *by one ox*, but you get my drift.) As for the not-so-imperially-inclined, the information that an acre is roughly 0.4 hectare, 40 are, or 4000 square meters is probably more relatable. Or "about the size of a football field"? ;-)

Comment: I guess that some of those farmers were sephards instead, and their herds grazed in mostly non-cultivable areas, which makes even more room for the rest.

Comment: If you are not familiar with acres: 2,5 acre ~ 1 hectare (which is 100x100m).

Comment: @DevSolar football or football?

Comment: @KevinVanDyck: Yes.

Comment: @DevSolar The same is true for most units devised before industrialisation or widespread numeracy/literacy. A league was the distance a man could walk in an hour, a furlong was the distance an ox team could pull a plow before they needed to rest, a hide was the area of land needed to support an average household, etc.

Comment: @anaximander Let's not forget that even time was very imprecise.

Comment: @Rekesoft The Japanese did not keep much in the way of herd animals.  Rice cultivation doesn't typically use animal labor, the traditional Japanese diet has no dairy, and they didn't typically use wool.

Comment: @KevinVanDyck Surely you mean metric football or imperial football?

Comment: @StevenBurnap I know, that's why I changed my initial "many" for "some". But I don't know if they were so few of them to be irrelevant. In any case, oxen have been used in Japan for centuries, and they must be bred.

Comment: @DevSolar: It's not horribly imprecise if it's never used for precise measurements. For example, 1ft is not precisely one human foot's length, but it's also never used as the unit of measurement of actual human feet so the distinction is irrelevant. If farmland was distributed so that every farmer could plow it in exactly one day, an default acre would not be precise enough. But that's not the case, it's only used to approximate size in casual conversation. Before standards were a thing, people always just described things as "about yea big" in whatever unit they though made the most sense.

Comment: @DevSolar "If the ground is difficult to plow, does an acre become smaller?" Probably yes.  For the uses that "acre" was originally used for, that's not a particular problem.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Like in telling us how much land the average Japanese farmer had? ;-) It's OK, I get your point. I just think it's a bit silly to defend imperial measurements on the basis of how "intuitive" they are, when it's just a matter of habit, and *especially* when the "intuitive" basis of the measurement is something nearly no-one today can actually relate to. (Tell me, when did you last see an ox used for plowing?)

Comment: @DevSolar Nobody in this thread (apart from you) has suggested imperial measurements are "intuitive". I think you are reacting to something that isn't here. (I don't doubt that the suggestion has been made elsewhere - but in that case, react there instead.)

Comment: @MartinBonner: Denis made that very first comment telling people "what an acre is", when, in effect, it's nothing more than another measurement for area, roughly equivalent to 0.4 ha / 40 a / 4000m^2 in metric, an information I considered missing from his comment and more useful for visualization than "the area a man can plow in one day" (something I would fully expect people *using* imperial measurements every day to actually *know*). Which is why I made *my* comment. The rest of this "thread" is a massive sense of humor failure.